# How to cast an object to a generic return type, when the return type is a generic interface?

Tags: c#, generics, iconvertible

I have an astoundingly ugly method that's supposed to pull assorted data from a database, and use it construct an object of a requested type. The goal is to pull the assorted ugliness into a single place, so that classes that derive from the class containing this method can be relatively clean.

I'm not having a problem with when it's supposed to return a single object, even when the type is nullable:

```
protected T getValue<T>(ParameterObject myParameterObject)
{
    var typeOfT = typeof (T);

    if (typeOfT == typeof(bool))
    {
        string val = this.getValue(myParameterObject);

        if (val == null)
            return default(T);

        bool rVal;
        if (!Boolean.TryParse(val, out rVal))
            return default(T);

        return changeType<T>(rVal);
    }

    if (typeOfT == typeof (double?))
    {
        string val = this.getValue(myParameterObject);

        if (val == null)
            return default(T);

        double rVal;
        if (!Double.TryParse(val, out rVal))
            return default(T);

        return changeType<T>(rVal);
    }

    [...]
}

public static T changeType<T>(object value)
{
    var t = typeof(T);
    if (!t.IsGenericType || t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Nullable<>))
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);

    if (value == null)
        return default(T);

    t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
}
```

Unfortunately, I have cases in which my desired return type is IList, where I want to return a List:

```
protected T getValue<T>(ParameterObject myParameterObject)
{
    var typeOfT = typeof (T);

    if (typeOfT.IsGenericType)
    {
        if (typeOfT.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IList<>))
        {
            var genericArgumentType = typeOfT.GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault();
            var baseType = typeof (List<>);
            var genericType = baseType.MakeGenericType(new[] {genericArgumentType});

            var rVal = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);

            [code to populate the list] 

            return changeType<T>(rVal);
        }

    [...]
}
```

I can't return an rVal, because it's an object, not an instance of T.  But my changeType() function is failing, with an error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.

So, I have a generic method for which the return type is IList, and I have an object which is a List, but my reference to it is of type Object.  How do I cast it so that I can return it from the function?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but why are you doing `return changeType<T>(rVal);` instead of `return (T)(object)rVal;`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);` line is failing because your `value` object does not implement `IConvertible`.

From [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx)

> [...] For the conversion to succeed, value must implement the [IConvertible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, because the method simply wraps a call to an appropriate [IConvertible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The method requires that conversion of value to conversionType be supported.

To fix this, I'm not sure of a general way but for the specific case of `value` being of an `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<>` type, then you could try to cast then perform a `value.Select(x => changeType<ListGenT>(x))` linq query.  By using your `changeType` method recursively this should handle nested generic types as well.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, but if I changed my methods to return List<T>, instead of creating a List<T> and returning an IList<T>, the issue went away.